# Electron-forge npm run make "Error: The main entry point to your app was not found."

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-forge

My electron app is in its final stage where I try to use electron-forge to make it into an executable. Running it through `npm run start` gave no problem, however when running `npm run make` new errors came up. I fixed all until this absurd error came up.

`An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge: Error: The main entry point to your app was not found. Make sure "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Programming\Lucrative Projects\studyplanner\src\main.js" exists and does not get ignored by your ignore option`

What makes this absurd is that the file indeed exists... [image]

Furthermore nothing in the package.json would indicate that something is ignored.

```
  "name": "studyplanner",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My electron app",
  "main": "./src/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "dev": "webpack --watch && electron .",
    "build": "rimraf ./public && mkdir public && webpack --progress -p",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.60",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.60",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.60",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.60",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.60",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack": "^6.0.0-beta.60",
    "@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "6.3.2",
    "css-loader": "3.6.0",
    "electron": "9.3.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.5.0",
    "node-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss": "7.0.32",
    "postcss-cssnext": "3.1.0",
    "postcss-import": "12.0.1",
    "postcss-load-config": "2.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-nesting": "7.0.1",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "style-loader": "1.2.1",
    "url-loader": "4.1.0",
    "webpack": "4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/node": "^7.14.9",
    "@babel/register": "^7.15.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9"
  },
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "studyplanner"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
          {
            "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
            "renderer": {
              "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
              "entryPoints": [
                {
                  "html": "./src/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/renderer.js",
                  "name": "main"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I looked in common.js where the error arose. I tried replacing line 155's `if (!(await fs.pathExists(mainScript)))` with `if (!(await fs.pathExists(originalMainScript)))` but that only made an `out` without any files in `resources/app`, only some in `.webpack`. Hopefully this error is not due to the out folder not generating the content.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when main.js was not contained in a subdirectory below  the directory containing package.json. The solution that worked for me was to create a symbolic link to main.js in a subdirectory. This seems to be a requirement of electron-forge.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

replace the `main` in `package.json` with .webpack/main

Answer (score 0):

To make it work for me, I had to remove the `./` from the start of my `main` declaration. So for you it would read `"main": "src/main.js"`

This is weird because it reports the file path correctly in the error message

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it changing

```
"main": "./out/main/index.js"
```

to

```
"main": "./dist/main/index.js"
```

It was fixed because I pointed the path where my compiled program was.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are struggling to get Electron to recognize the index.js within "./out/main/", I literally just renamed the `out` folder to `dist` and adjusted the the package.json file accordingly. Then it suddenly worked. Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to add `.js` at the end of `main` inside the `package.json` file

like so

```
{
  ...
  "main": "main.js",
  ...
}
```